# Find the previous 3 month average value in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I am attempting to get the last 3 months average of out%. so far could not find any sample  that suit for my requirement. Appreciate any help that could be provided.

There's a multiple column that i need to consider. I have to add the current month good% and the out% in the calculation to get the forecast.

This code gives me an error and the values reflected in the column is incorrect.
Sum([out]) / Sum([in]) over (LastPeriods(3,[month]))

```
Dt          TotalIN  TotalOut   Good     OUT%     Good%
```

```
2/1/2019    79606    51384      0        64.55%   0
3/1/2019    84194    61211      0        72.70%   0
4/1/2019    92458    67807      0        73.34%   0
5/1/2019    94531    66988      95       70.86%   0.10%
6/1/2019    29623    18181      2903     60.94%   9.73%
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for adding some data I could copy in. Below is the early morning hack I made a column of the summary table. I also binned the row axes to make this work.

**Column Calculation:**

```
(Sum([Good%]) * ((
 Sum([TotalOut]) OVER (Previous([Axis.Rows],3)) + Sum([TotalOut]) OVER (Previous([Axis.Rows],2)) + Sum([TotalOut]) OVER (Previous([Axis.Rows],1)))
/ (
 Sum([TotalIn]) OVER (Previous([Axis.Rows],3)) + Sum([TotalIn]) OVER (Previous([Axis.Rows],2)) + Sum([TotalIn]) OVER (Previous([Axis.Rows],1)))))
 + Sum([Out%])
```

**Row Axes:**

```
<BinByDateTime([Dt],"Year.Month",1)>
```

There might be a cleaner version with below but I'm not good with `THEN`. The problem with `LastPeriods` is that you want `NULL` if there aren't enough months.

`THEN If(Count() OVER (LastPeriods(3,[Axis.X]))=3,[Value],NULL)`

Comment: Hi A.Korinda. Thnks for the reply. using the code it gives me a different result. 
by the way, here is the exact formula.   
( Good% * 3 months average of  Out%) + Out%

This is the formula were i get the Good% and Out%
Good% =  Good / Total In
Out%  =  Total Out / Total In

Comment: Can you edit with R `dput` output or a delimited sample of the data in a comment I could copy paste?

Comment: Hi A.Korinda. what if the i will include the current month from the 3 months avg instead of previous month, what would be the changes  in the code that you have given.